# Laravel 4 Commands Directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have just realised in Laravel 4, we have the commands directory added to app/start/global.php. The directory contains nothing in it. Does this directory replace libraries in Laravel 3? I guess my classes will still work if I placed them in there, but would I be using it for the wrong purpose?

Comment: If your libraries classes are not database models you should create a new directory into your `app` folder then add it to `app/start/global.php` in `ClassLoader::addDirectories`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laravel 4 commands directory, is like the Laravel 3 tasks directory. So it is not the ideal place for your libraries. What is the recommended way to go? If your libraries classes are database models it should be place under `app/models`, otherwise you could create a new directory like `app/libraries` then modify: `app/start/global.php` and add the new directory path to the array in `ClassLoader::addDirectories(...)` method call.

**Extra information above related to Laravel 4 Commands:**

The main differences (advantages) of Laravel 4 Commands over Laravel 3 Tasks are:

1. Start writing a command is just matter of typing: `php artisan command:make MyCommand`.
2. Commands can have a set of *arguments* and *options*.
3. Commands need to be [registered in Artisan](http://laravel.com/docs/commands#registering-commands).

For more information read the docs about [Commands](http://laravel.com/docs/commands).